# Evenly distribute column widths in NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, swift4

What I want to do seems pretty simple. I want to have a table view that automatically distributes the width of my columns based on the size of the tableview. If the screen stretches, all the columns in the tableview should stretch as well. I don't want to explicitly set these widths. I have looked around but have not been able to find a solution. This is different from `columnAutoresizingStyle`. I have already set that to `uniformColumnAutoresizingStyle`. This is a OS X app not iOS so it uses a NSTableView not UITableView.